# "Github.com" go packages not showing in remote repository in Bitbucket

Tags: go, bitbucket

When I push my go code into my remote bitbucket repository, I don't see my files in github.com package folder instead I see this (this is a screen shot of my bitbucket repository, where I expect to find my go files):
[image]

I used this command to push my code into my remote repository:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push -u origin master
```

When I log into my Bitbucket account, **I expect to see my go files** inside the "drakecheckin/src/github.com/coopernurse" directory. However I do not see my go file instead I see an arrow pointing to a bunch of characters+numbers.

Comment: Wow. Please. Please give us the relevant information to help you. We aren't standing behind you .. and we certainly aren't mind readers. I am sorry but your screenshot and your single sentence make zero sense. You even have `revel` randomly tagged.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Are you pushing your _entire_ GOPATH up to Bitbucket?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I edited my post. Please let me know if I make sense now.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, Yes I am pushing my entire GOPATH up to Bitbucket.

Comment: @JimB, sorry about that. I posted my question without any clarification/explanation at first because I wanted to test out if I can post an image( this is the 1st time I am posting an image). I have edit my post. Would you be able to help now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Go get` will clone github repositories into the appropriate folder of your gopath. What you're seeing in BitBucket is a submodule. You can treat the folder as a subtree if you'd like to check it into version control.

Comment: I edit my post. I am trying to use git push to push my GOPATH into Bitbucket. However, when I logged into Bitbucket, I do not see my file instead I see an arrow pointing to a bunch of char+numbers.

Comment: Right, what you're seeing is a way git stores references to other git repositories. Try taking a look at this tutorial for an alternative approach: https://github.com/jamesgraves/example-go-app